# Crazy glue vs Nail glue

Tags: adhesion

So I have a nail repair kit, consisting of nail glue(ethyl cyanoacrylate), powder and a nail buffer. I'm almost of out glue yet stick have a bunch of powder. One of the crazy glue tiny bottles has almost the same name(ethyl 2-cyanoacrylate). Can I refill the nail glue with the crazy glue?

Short version -
Nail glue - ethyl cyanoacrylate VS ethyl 2-cyanoacrylate - super glue
Are these the same?

Answer (score 1):

they are the same chemical yes - (the 2 just refers to the position of the side branch.)
I Would not expose the glue to air unnecessarily as any moisture will make it harden . I can not say for you using it on your nails for insurance reasons ( but scientifically they are the same )